# Iphone simulator and webcam

Tags: iphone, camera, ios-simulator

Can we make able the iphone simulator to capture an image via webcam, I've written a program to take image from iphone camera. Can i test this with the iphone simulator??? Pls help

Comment: In case you only want to add some images to your simulator and then test it, what you can do is drag-drop the image on the simulator(it will open the image in safari of the simulator) and then simply click and hold on that image to save it in the simulator's photo library.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot take image via Mac's webcam from iPhone Simulator. For camera, you need to test it on a device.

Comment: What happens if the camera methods are accessed in the simulator? Do I get an error?

Comment: I think you will get some error message which conveys that camera is not available on this device.

Comment: you won't get an error, you will just get a view that says it's a camera simulation.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine if this would be possible on the Simulator, your Mac camera resoultion would be very different from the device one and your mac performances too. This could lead to bad surprises when moving and testing the application on the device.

Comment: the reason that this doubt came to me is that i've seen such features in the simulators for android and other such platforms. Anyway, thanks for your replies. Its great that apple didn't included such an option, which would have led the developers  to make a mess of it.

Comment: There'd be nothing to stop the webcam image being scaled to exactly the resolution of the iphone camera.  I think it should work... partly coz I'm trying to write an app and I haven't had my phone delivered yet!

Answer (score 3):

(Sorry for my english)

In android world, the phone emulator don't have a live camera preview so the solution is create a "Webcam Server"  running on emulator host (PC/Mac). This program is a socket server to capture frames from the built-in Webcam and transmit them using a socket.

Then in the phone code (android emulator) you can read the frame through socket and then shows and simulate a real phone camera.

Is that posible in iPhone simulator?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use mac's camera. For camera, you need to test it on a device.

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1):

> The hardware features that are not simulated as of iOS 8.2 are:
>
> - Motion support (accelerometer and gyroscope) are unsupported.
> - Audio and video input (camera and microphone) are unsupported.
> - Proximity sensor
> - Barometer Ambient light sensor