# Can you use a webcam for the iPhone's camera in the Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Is it possible to use a webcam in the place of the iPhone's built-in camera within the iPhone Simulator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can do I test a camera in the iPhone simulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168484/how-can-do-i-test-a-camera-in-the-iphone-simulator)

Comment: See also [iPhone camera in simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579792/iphone-camera-in-simulator) and [Iphone simulator and webcam](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898983/iphone-simulator-and-webcam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tools provided with Apple's SDK do not support using a Mac's webcam in the iPhone Simulator.

I suppose you could develop/write your own AV class extensions or AV delegate calling methods, and plug them in for testing in the Simulation environment.

Comment: but we take image form mac we cam and pass it likes object to iphone simulator......is it possible to make for iphone simulator

Comment: but we take image form mac web cam and pass it likes object to iphone simulator......is it possible to make

Comment: i think you should have to try for right the driver for usb cam of iphone then it will sport on you simulator , and  tell me if you done because me also doing search on this

Comment: k i also will inform after get it........U also please share with me.......................Thanks for U....